# I'm having problem adding my signup form into my web, when I add the form, the nav bar is mess up

Tags: html, css

I have a sign up form and login form, which I'm trying to add to my web page, but when I do, it mess up my nav bar. I think it might have to do with the CSS, but I am not sure. Please help a beginner out lol. And the CSS is for the forms, not the web.

sign up:

```
<div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-4 offset-md-4 form-div">
            <form action = "signup.php" method = "post">
            <h3 class = "text-center">Registration</h3>

            <?php if(count($errors) > 0): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row m-0">
   <div class="col-6">
<div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "fname">First Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "<?php $fname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php $lname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "username">User Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "username" value = "<?php $username; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>


        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "email">Email</label>
            <input type = "email" name = "email" value = "<?php $email; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>


        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "phone">Phone</label>
            <input type = "tele" name = "phone" value = "<?php $phone; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>


        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "password">Password</label>
            <input type = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>


        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "passwordConf">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type = "password" name = "passwordConf" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>

            <div class = "form-group">
               <button type="submit" name="signup-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather&display=swap');

.form-div{
    margin:50px auto 50px;
    padding: 25px 15px 10px 15px;
    border: 4px solid #80ced7;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-size:1.1em;
    font-family: 'Merriweather&display=swap', serif;
}

.form-control:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}

form p{
    font-size: .89;
}

.form-div.login{
    margin-top: 100px;

}

.logout{
    color:red;

}
```

web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Register</title>

    <!-- Google font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400%7CSource+Sans+Pro:700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.css" />

    <!-- Font Awesome Icon -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Custom stlylesheet -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
    <!-- HEADER -->
    <header id="home">
        <!-- NAVGATION -->
        <nav id="main-navbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <!-- Logo -->
                    <div class="navbar-brand">
                        <a class="logo" href="indexx.php"><img src="img/tree.jpg" alt="logo"></a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Logo -->

                    <!-- Mobile toggle -->
                    <button class="navbar-toggle-btn">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </button>
                    <!-- Mobile toggle -->

                    <!-- Mobile Search toggle -->
                    <button class="search-toggle-btn">
                            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    <!-- Mobile Search toggle -->
                </div>

                <!-- Search -->
                <div class="navbar-search">
                    <button class="search-btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    <div class="search-form">
                        <form method = "GET" action = "search.php">
                            <?php $search = ''; ?>
                            <input class="input" type="text" name="query" id = "query" value = "<?php $search ?>" placeholder="Search">
                            <input type = "submit" name = "search">
                        </form>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Search -->

                <!-- Nav menu -->
                <ul class="navbar-menu nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="indexx.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Causes</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="single-cause.html">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Events</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="single-event.html">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Member</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="report.php">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Nav menu -->
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- /NAVGATION -->

    <!-- SECTION -->
    <div class="section">
        <!-- container -->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- row -->
            <div class="row">
            <div class = "col-md-4 offset-md-4 form-div">
            <form action = "register.php" method = "post">
            <h3 class = "text-center">Registration</h3>

            <?php if(count($errors) > 0): ?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $error; ?></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="row m-0">
   <div class="col-6">
<div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "fname">First Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "<?php $fname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-6">
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "lname">Last Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php $lname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>
        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "username">User Name</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "username" value = "<?php $username; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>


        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "email">Email</label>
            <input type = "email" name = "email" value = "<?php $email; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>


        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "phone">Phone</label>
            <input type = "tele" name = "phone" value = "<?php $phone; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>


        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "password">Password</label>
            <input type = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>


        <div class = "form-group">
            <label for = "passwordConf">Confirm Password</label>
            <input type = "password" name = "passwordConf" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>

            <div class = "form-group">
               <button type="submit" name="signup-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
```

The nav bar drop down and cover half of the form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see closing tags for form and div's above the form. You should link bootstrap in head not inside the form. Why you have li inside error div but no ul? Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class = "container">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-md-4 offset-md-4 form-div">
      <form action = "signup.php" method = "post">
        <h3 class = "text-center">Registration</h3>
        <?php if(count($errors) > 0): ?>
          <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <?php foreach($errors as $error): ?>
              <p><?php echo $error; ?></p>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="row m-0">
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class = "form-group">
              <label for = "fname">First Name</label>
              <input type = "text" name = "fname" value = "<?php $fname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6">
            <div class = "form-group">
              <label for = "lname">Last Name</label>
              <input type = "text" name = "lname" value = "<?php $lname; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
          <label for = "username">User Name</label>
          <input type = "text" name = "username" value = "<?php $username; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
          <label for = "email">Email</label>
          <input type = "email" name = "email" value = "<?php $email; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
          <label for = "phone">Phone</label>
          <input type = "tele" name = "phone" value = "<?php $phone; ?>" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
          <label for = "password">Password</label>
          <input type = "password" name = "password" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
          <label for = "passwordConf">Confirm Password</label>
          <input type = "password" name = "passwordConf" class = "form-control form-control-lg">
        </div>

        <div class = "form-group">
          <button type="submit" name="signup-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I had to delete some part of the codes because the code was too long, so I deleted the closing tags part.

Comment: How do you expect from us to help you if you send a piece of the code? Maybe the problem is in the code that you didn't show us.